# Can I create a virtual webcam and stream data to it?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, webcam

I am looking to stream a video from ffmpeg to OpenCV (a video manipulation library) and I am stumped.  My idea is to create a virtual webcam device and then stream a video from ffmpeg to this device and the device will in turn stream like a regular webcam.  My motivation is for OpenCV.  OpenCV can read in a video stream from a webcam and go along its merry way.

But is this possible?  I know there is software to create a virtual webcam, but can it accept a video stream (like from ffmpeg) and can it stream this video like a normal webcam? (I am working in a cygwin environment , if that is important)

Comment: i am looking for similar solution. i want to feed my own video stream to virtual webcam which would act like normal webcam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fool OpenCV into thinking the file is a webcam. You just need to add a delay between each frame. This code will do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    VideoCapture cap; 
    cap.open("/Users/steve/Development/opencv2/opencv_extra/testdata/python/videos/bmp24.avi");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        printf("Unable to open video file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat frame; 
    namedWindow("video", 1); 
    for(;;) {
        cap >> frame; 
        if(!frame.data) 
            break; 
        imshow("video", frame); 
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) //Show each frame for 30ms
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit: trying to read from a file being created by ffmpeg:**

```
    for(;;) {
        cap >> frame; 
        if(frame.data) 
            imshow("video", frame); //show frame if successfully loaded
        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //Wait 30 ms. Quit if user presses escape 
            break;
    }
```

I'm not sure how it will handle getting a partial frame at the end of the file while ffmpeg is still creating it.

Comment: Hmmm, but I am trying to do this in real-time from ffmpeg.  Can I stream to a file from ffmpeg while OpenCV is reading it at the same time?  I don't want a process of making a file with ffmpeg and then opening it later for OpenCV.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. You can certainly try to read from the file that ffmpeg is creating. You'd want to change the tests in the for loop. I'll edit the answer to show what I would try.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is [VideoCapture::Open](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-open), which can open both video devices and files.

If you're using C, the equivalents are `cvCaptureFromFile` and `cvCaptureFromCAM`.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more clear.  I have had success in opening both files and webcams, but I get stuck when I try to stream a video from ffmpeg to my OpenCV C++ tool.  So I thought that I could create a virtual webcam so that OpenCV thinks that the video coming from it is an actual device...but I'm not sure if this is possible.